# How prevent form submit in google apps script

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, iframe

I am importing a form written in GoogleApps Script into an iframe on a page built with Squarespace but for the life of me cannot prevent the form from submitting. I am using:

```
window.addEventListener( 'load', preventFormSubmit );
```

as suggested in GAS documentation but this does not seem to be triggering the preventFormSubmit function. Instead, when the submit button is clicked the form submits and goes to a blank google page. Also the alerts in the preventFormSubmit function (now commented out) never display which suggests that the form is never called.

I have spent days on this, cannot find an answer anywhere and can no longer see the woods for the trees. Any clues as to what I am doing wrong?

Squarespace is a website builder which enables one to embed code, in this case as an iframe.

My code:
js.html:

```
    <script>

   function preventFormSubmit() {
    //alert( "prevent form submit triggered" );
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
      });
    }
    //alert( "forms prevented from submitting: " = forms.length );
  }

  window.addEventListener( "ready", preventFormSubmit );
  
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler( showSuccess )
      .withFailureHandler( showError )
      .processForm_1( formObject );
  }
   </script>
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
  <base target="_top" >
  
  
  <?!= include('css'); ?>
  <?!= include('js'); ?>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="formDiv" class="card" >
    <h2 id="title" >Alternative Booking form</h2>
    
    <form id="alternative-booking-form-1" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)" >
      <fieldset>
        <legend>About You</legend>
        <p>Please tell us a bit about yourself. 
        </p>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" form="alternative-booking-form-1" 
                                                  placeholder="your first name" value="" required 
    /><br />
        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" form="alternative-booking-form-1" 
                                                  placeholder="your last name" value="" required 
    /><br />
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" form="alternative-booking-form-1" 
                                    placeholder="your title, eg: mr, mrs, ms etc" value="" /><br>  
                                                                   
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Your Contact Details</legend>
        <p>We will only use your contact details in case we need to contact you with regard to 
      this booking, unless you consent
          to further communications, as offered later in this booking process.</p>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" form="alternative-booking-form-1" 
                                                  placeholder="your email address" value="" 
    required /><br />
        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" form="alternative-booking-form-1" 
                                                  placeholder="phone" value="" required /><br />                                          
      </fieldset> 
                                                                                                    
      <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" id="form" name="form" form="alternative-booking-form-1" value="1"  />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" form="alternative-booking-form-1" 
     class="red" value="Next &rarr;"  /> 
        <br /> 
        <br />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="output" name="output" ></div>
  
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
  <base target="_top" >
  
  
  <?!= include('css'); ?>
  <?!= include('js'); ?>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="formDiv" class="card" >
    <h2 id="title" >Alternative Booking form</h2>
    
    <form id="alternative-booking-form-1" >
      <fieldset>
        <legend>About You</legend>
        <p>Please tell us a bit about yourself. 
        </p>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" form="alternative-booking-form-1" 
                                                  placeholder="your first name" value="" required 
    /><br />
        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" form="alternative-booking-form-1" 
                                                  placeholder="your last name" value="" required 
    /><br />
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" form="alternative-booking-form-1" 
                                    placeholder="your title, eg: mr, mrs, ms etc" value="" /><br>  
                                                                   
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Your Contact Details</legend>
        <p>We will only use your contact details in case we need to contact you with regard to 
      this booking, unless you consent
          to further communications, as offered later in this booking process.</p>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" form="alternative-booking-form-1" 
                                                  placeholder="your email address" value="" 
    required /><br />
        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" form="alternative-booking-form-1" 
                                                  placeholder="phone" value="" required /><br />                                          
      </fieldset> 
                                                                                                    
      <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" id="form" name="form" form="alternative-booking-form-1" value="1"  />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" form="alternative-booking-form-1" 
     class="red" value="Next &rarr;"  /> 
        <br /> 
        <br />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="output" name="output" ></div>
  <script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("alternative-booking-form-1").addEventListener( "ready", handleFormSubmit );
  }
   
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler( showSuccess )
      .withFailureHandler( showError )
      .processForm_1( formObject );
  }
   </script>    
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it still posts the form and I want to prevent that. The trouble is that the default behaviour happens before handleFormSubmit() gets time to run - even when I replace handleFormSubmit() in the event listenener with preventDefault

Comment: I don't see how it could .  It's not of type submit and there is no submit attribute.

Comment: however, i would like to know your thinking. what is the effect of of moving the event listener from loading in the dochead until after the body has almost completely loaded?

Comment: Because the script does not need to run until all of the contents has been loaded

Comment: OK, I have implemented it correctly now, I think. The form no longer submits but does not trigger the handleFormsubmit() function.  

what does the window.onload statement mean? It reads to me that when the html document is fully loaded, get the form and wait for it to be ready and when it is call handleFormSubmit(). is this correct? If so, when is the form ready? when it is loaded, or when the button has been clicked?