# How to prevent a Google Form from submitting programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-docs, google-forms

I have a Google Form with an attached Google Apps Script and I am doing some advanced form validation in it, stuff that's not possible with Google's built-in validation.  Problem is, the response gets recorded regardless of what happens inside the script.  Is it possible for the script to prevent form submission?  Something like `event.preventDefault()` in Javascript?

UPDATE: This question may be moot because my custom validation relies on being able to show some modal or message to the user, like is possible in GAS for Sheets.  But apparently, Google Forms does not support this.  I will leave this question open for a day as I'm still curious about if it's possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How prevent form submit in google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68377779/how-prevent-form-submit-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Your question is related to Google Form which is not HTML form. Is my understanding correct? About `Is it possible for the script to prevent form submission?`, in this case, do you want to close Google Form to avoid the submission by the user? Or, Google Form is opening and when the user is submitted, do you want to cancel the submission? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: thanks @Justinas, I saw that question before I posted but it doesn't apply because that user actually created an HTML form based on Google Forms, but it is not a true Google Form hosted by Google.

Comment: hi @Tanaike, thank you for your response and actually, your English is perfect.  I want to cancel the submission and show some message but actually, it seems I can't show any message anyway.  I will update the question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your question is related to Google Form. About `I want to cancel the submission and show some message but actually, it seems I can't show any message anyway.`, unfortunately, the custom message cannot be shown after the submission. In this case, after the submission, the confirmation message can be modified. But, in this case, the updated message is shown after the next submission. And, I think that the submitted data can be canceled.

Comment: By the way, I cannot understand the relationship between `I have a Google Form with an attached Google Apps Script ` and `like is possible in GAS for Sheets`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, in GAS (Google Apps Script) for Google Sheets, you can show alerts and prompts programmatically, as a response to user input.  I was hoping that this would be possible in Google Forms as well but now I understand that it isn't possible.

Comment: Based on my research, Google's documentation doesn't have the specifics that you're looking for in Google Forms. I suggest submitting a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) as it is the best way to have them check on your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments, everyone.  I wanted to close this question but apparently I can't do that unilaterally.

Anyway, the answer seems to be that there is no way to prevent submission of the form programmatically and what's more, there isn't even any way to show a message or alert to a user, so there's no way to do custom validation outside of Google's built-in, and rather basic, validation.